# Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) STOP code 0x00000116 on game close

Tags: civilization-5, technical-issues

I encountered a strange crash on closing Civilization V.  Usually the game closes fine, but on occasion the crash presents as follows:

1. I click "Exit to Windows"
2. Game closes, desktop shows, but begins flickering
3. After a few seconds of flickering, blue screen of death

I did find a workaround and will post as an answer, as I think this issue could potentially affect other DirectX games.  For Civ5 specifically, I did come across a compilation thread for troubleshooting [other types of crashes](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1440616).

To verify symptoms, I used [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html), a visualizer for windows dump files.  After running it and selecting Options->Lower Pane Mode->Blue Screen in XP Style, my crash dump looks like this:[image]

Comment: Any time you see a BSOD it's the fault of a driver, faulty hardware, or Windows itself. Try updating your video drivers and see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: +1, yeah, I agree -- this is usually the case.  For this problem, I did just that, updating to latest ATI HD6900 series drivers.  I got a phone call just as I was about to type up my answer, so my workaround response was a bit delayed =)

Answer (score 4):

The error suggests it's a DirectX crash, but it is not enough to update graphics drivers or confirm that DirectX is up to date.  The breakthrough moment came for me when I found this Windows [this Windows post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/windows-7-constantly-crashing-blue-screenstop/a94570b1-cf0a-4b6e-aa42-44338eb00495) explaining the error.  The important part is:

> Andre.Ziegler replied on  July 12, 2010
>   Bug Check 0x116: VIDEO_TDR_ERROR
>   This indicates that an attempt to reset the display driver and recover from a timeout [failure]

And then I remembered that during those occasional crashes, I had walked away from the game.  My monitor was set to turn off after 10 minutes, though when I came back the game seemed fine and I continued to play without issues.  Later when I exited, the crash occurred.

My workaround is to use a script to set the timeout to "Never" (can also be manually done through Control Panel->Power Options->Turn off the display->Never), and when the game finished, to set it back to 10 minutes:

*CivilizationV_DX11_nosleep.bat*

```
@echo off
REM The purpose of this script is to prevent a possible BSOD crash on 
REM   Civ5 closing if at one point the monitor went to sleep
REM Place this script in same folder as CivilizationV_DX11 executable
REM Optionally, make a shortcut to it on your desktop

REM sets the monitor to never timeout
powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0

REM open civ5
call CivilizationV_DX11.exe

REM revert to preferred setting (e.g. 10 minutes)
powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac 10
```